# How to use XmlWriter recursively?

Tags: c#, .net

My code crashes when using the XmlWriter, saying it is used by another process.

```
    private void generateXml(Control receivedControl)
    {
        foreach (Control subCtrl in receivedControl.Controls)
        {
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("C:\\ui.xml"))
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement(subCtrl.Name);
                generateXml(subCtrl);
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            generateXml(c);
        }
    }
```

Here's the error I get debugging:

> Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'C:\ui.xml' because it is being used by another process.

EDIT: So thanks to you I've managed to get the recursion working, but it only writes the last object in the xml file, anybody knows why? Here's the updated code:

```
    private void generateXml(XmlWriter receivedWriter, Control receivedControl)
    {
        receivedWriter.WriteStartElement(receivedControl.Name);
        foreach (Control subCtrl in receivedControl.Controls)
        {
            generateXml(receivedWriter, subCtrl);
        }
        receivedWriter.WriteEndElement();
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;

            using(XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("c:\\ui.xml", settings))
            {
                writer.WriteStartDocument();
                writer.WriteStartElement("Form");
                generateXml(writer, c);
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndDocument();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Move the `using` outside the `foreach`.

Comment: @NikoDrašković No. It needs to move out of the recursion.

Comment: You should consider creating the XmlWriter only once may be a static variable. Once created successive recursion iterations can check for the existence and just use the created object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file when accessed by the XmlWriter will become locked, so an subsequent attempts to read it result in error.

You can change the function to pass the writer as a parameter, thereby have one copy and hopefully avoid the issue.

```
private void generateXml(XmlWriter writer, Control receivedControl)
{
    foreach (Control subCtrl in receivedControl.Controls)
    {
            writer.WriteStartElement(subCtrl.Name);
            generateXml(writer, subCtrl);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("C:\\ui.xml"))
    {
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        writer.WriteStartElement(this.Name); // This is the document element
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            generateXml(writer, c);
        }
        writer.WriteEndDocument(); // Close any open tags
    }
}
```

Above is a sample - not tested.

Edit : Updated to include root element

Comment: Hey, thanks, it got me working. Would you please look at the edit, I have problem with writing with the xml writer.

Comment: @Kajzer In an xml file, there can only be one root element.  Your code snippet is attempting to write all the controls as the root element, and the writer overwrites the previous root element with the new, until only last one remains.  To work around this, wrap all the controls into a parent document element.  I have added the code to my earlier snippet.

Comment: Thanks, I already had it wrapped around, so I don't understand why it wouldn't work. I once again updated the original entry.

Answer (score 0):

that's because you're opening multiple instances of your `XmlWriter writer` at once.

What you should do, is put your `using` statement outside the recursive function, and then pass your `XmlWriter` in

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("C:\\ui.xml"))
{
    generateXml(c, writer);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use a File that shares write access

```
        using (var f = new FileStream("C:\\ui.xml",      FileMode.Append,FileAccess.Write,FileShare.Write))
            {
                using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(f))                 
                {
                    writer.WriteStartElement(subCtrl.Name);
                    generateXml(subCtrl);
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                }
            }
```